# ie11 ignoring specific block of css but not entire stylesheet

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

ie11 is ignoring this css:

```
.canopy_banner .banner_text {
  max-width: 335px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="row-fluid-wrapper">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span5">
      <div class="banner_text">
        {% if module.banner_content.tagline %}<span class="accent_text" style="color:{{ module.banner_content.tagline_color.color }};">{{ module.banner_content.tagline }}</span>{% endif %}
        {% if module.banner_content.h1_header %}<h1>{{ module.banner_content.h1_header }}</h1>{% endif %}
        {% if module.banner_content.richtext_field %}{{ module.banner_content.richtext_field }}{% endif %}

        {% if module.banner_content.buttons_ %}{% if module.button_group.type_of_buttons  == "cta" %}{% for item in module.button_group.cta_repeater %}{% cta guid="{{ item }}" %}{% endfor %}{% elif module.button_group.type_of_buttons  == "nam" %}{% for item in module.button_group.link_repeater %}<a href="{{ page_by_id(item.link_url).absolute_url }}" class="cta_button">{{ item.link_text }}</a>{% endfor %}{% endif %}{% endif %}

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span7 ban_hide">
      {% if module.banner_content.right_side_image.src %}
        <img src="{{ module.banner_content.right_side_image.src }}" alt="{{ module.banner_content.right_side_image.alt }}" style="width: {{ module.banner_content.image_width }}%;">
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but the entire rest of the styles are being applied to the page. I cannot figure out why. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your id's, classes, etc to be sure you're referencing them properly and not missing any child-elements e.g. a `div`, `li`, etc nested below `.canopy_banner .banner_text`.

Seeing the html code for that snippet would be helpful also